# Bug in math.stackexchange MathJax editor

Tags: bug, mathjax, editor

When answering a question the editor sometimes pops up an image which covers the line one is trying to edit as seen in the image below.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

My usual fix is to copy all the content, cancel the edit, reopen the editor and paste the content. But this happens so frequently it becomes tiresome.

[image: MathJax problem]

Comment: What browser are you using?  I've never encountered anything like what you captured in your screen shot.

Comment: I am using the latest Chrome browser on Ubuntu linux. But the same thing occurred in previous versions.

Comment: Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)